# Polygon in Cesium

Tags: polygon, cesium

I try to show a polygon in Cesium, this is my code:

```
const positions = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromRadiansArray([
    -1.3194369277314022, 0.6988062530900625,
    -1.3193955980204217, 0.6988091578771254,
    -1.3193931220959367, 0.698743632490865,
    -1.3194358224045408, 0.6987471965556998,
]);

const polygon = viewer.entities.add({
    polygon: {
        hierarchy: positions,
        material: Cesium.Color.RED.withAlpha(0.5),
        classificationType: Cesium.ClassificationType.BOTH,
    },
});

// Get the bounding sphere of the polygon's hierarchy
const boundingSphere = Cesium.BoundingSphere.fromPoints(positions);

// Zoom to the polygon's bounding sphere
viewer.camera.viewBoundingSphere(boundingSphere, new Cesium.HeadingPitchRange(0.0, -0.5, boundingSphere.radius + 500.0));
viewer.camera.lookAtTransform(Cesium.Matrix4.IDENTITY);
```

This code work fine in sandcastle, but when I try in my local environment the terrain loading and zooming work properly, but the polygon doesn't show, it must be problem with this part of code:

```
const polygon = viewer.entities.add({
    polygon: {
        hierarchy: positions,
        material: Cesium.Color.RED.withAlpha(0.5),
        classificationType: Cesium.ClassificationType.BOTH,
    },
});
```

Any one know whats the problem so that I can see polygon in my local environment?

Comment: Do you get any console errors/messages? And is the viewer in your local environment also called "viewer" i.e. are you using `const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");` ?